# Gracefully handle errors in Java with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

In my current project, I'm consuming a lot of JSON string. Because of this, I created a utility method to handle the JSONExceptions thrown by the "org.json" tools. Here's my current approach:

My json handler

```
public static <R> R handleJSONException(String operation, String params, String jsonString, FunctionWithJSONString<R> function) {

    try {
        return function.process(jsonString);
    } catch(JSONException jsonEx) {
        throw new myRunTimeException(
            StatusCode.ERROR_PARSING_JSON,
            "Error occurred while attempting to parse json: \"" + jsonString + "\"",
            "JSON parsing error occurred during operation, " + operation ", with params: " + params); 
    }
}
```

My custom functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FunctionWithJSONString<R> {
    public R process(String jsonString) throws JSONException;
}
```

Here's an example of its use:

```
public Object getObjectFromJSONString(final String json) {

    String operation = "Get an Object from some source";
    String params = "";

    return handleJSONException(operation, params, json, (jsonString) -> {
        JSONObject body = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        return body.getObject("object");
    })
}
```

(Of course this code is very simplified. It would normally be split up into sub methods; and the "handleJSONException" does some verification on the json before passing it, but this gives the jist of it)

The problem is that I don't like either having these lambdas every time I process JSON, or having to have a method processAndHandleJSON that just passes a reference to a sub method processJSON every time I deal with JSONExceptions (though I much prefer this approach to anything else I've seen).

I thought maybe I could use some aspect oriented programming instead. So, I came up with this design (excluding config class):

An annotation to signal a join point:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface JSONHandler {
}
```

The advice used at the join point:

```
@Aspect
public class JSONExceptionAdvice {

    @Around(@annotation(JSONHandler))
    public Object wrapJSONHandlingMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws throwable {
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs);
        } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
            //Some method that throws the "myRunTimeException" with necessary parameters
        }
            return null;
    }
}
```

Here would be an example of it's use:

```
@JSONHandler
public Object getObjectFromJSON(final String json) {
    JSONObject body = new JSONObject(json);
    return body.getObject("object");
}
```

However, this doesn't compile. In order to get it to compile and have the aspect catch the error, the "getObjectFromJSON" method would need a "throws JSONException" in the signature. Which would mean that I would still need a try/catch somewhere up the ladder. And to make matters worse, it would be an empty try/catch, which looks ugly, or to some one who doesn't know it was handled lower, lazy.

I would like it if my annotation could suppress "Unhandled JSONException" warnings in the compiler, but this is not an easy thing to do, from what I understand. Any other ideas I've thought of go right back to what I had before, but more verbose and top heavy.

Does anyone have any ideas on how AspectJ could be used to achieve the desired goal in a clean manner? Is the goal clearly stated? Could anyone recommend another approach that's better than either of these?

I've looked at other issues on StackOverflow, like [Exception handling through spring AOP + Aspectj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797157/exception-handling-through-spring-aop-aspectj), but either they use the empty try/catch, or ignore the unhandled exception problem altogether.

P.S. Although this is specific to json handling, I would like to apply this to a few other common errors. So, although org.json answers are welcome, I'll most likely accept the most generic answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your requirements correctly, but if you need to eliminate the need to catch the checked `org.json.JSONException`-s (make it behave like it would be a `RuntimeException`), then what you need is the AspectJ `declare soft` statement. Declare soft will wrap your checked `org.json.JSONException` with an unchecked `org.aspectj.lang.SoftException`. This is only available with native AspectJ syntax and you would have to switch to the AspectJ compiler to compile your project (so you won't get compile errors for not catching the checked exception or not declaring them to be propagated with the `throws` keyword in client methods).

```
public aspect JSONExceptionAdvice {

    declare soft: org.json.JSONException: @annotation(JSONHandler);

    after() throwing(org.json.JSONException e): @annotation(JSONHandler) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } 

}
```

Note that with the `after throwing` advice you don't suppress the `org.json.JSONException`, it will still propagate up through the stack (though it will be *softened*), so it's mostly good for logging purposes. If you need to suppress the exception, or do any other kind of compensation you'll need to use an `around` advice instead of `after throwing`.